# Receiving unknown file size in c# socket

Tags: c#, sockets

Program locks itself when it is downloading the file according to the code below: What might be the problem ?

```
if (bufferInfo.Contains("fileExists"))
{
    FileStream downloadFileStream = new FileStream(folderName + "\\" + requestFileName.Text, FileMode.Create);
    activityLog.AppendText("File is found, it will be downloaded !");
    byte[] myReadBufferExists = new byte[8196];

    do
    {
        bytesRead = clientSocket.Receive(myReadBufferExists);
        downloadFileStream.Write(myReadBufferExists,0,bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead != 0);

    downloadFileStream.Close();
    clientSocket.Close();
    bufferInfo.Replace("fileExists","");
    activityLog.AppendText("File has been received now writing to the disk...");    
}
```

Comment: Where does it lock? Did you set a breakpoint? Done some basic debugging?

Comment: Maybe your server doesn't close the socket and your client waits at `clientSocket.Receive`

Comment: On a side note, how did you come up with 8196 as a good buffer size?

Answer (score 2):

It locks on the `clientSocket.Receive(myReadBufferExists)` call. This is because Receive, by default, will try to fill the buffer you pass it. If you endlessly call Receive, it will eventually block when there's no more data.

Couple options:

- Before you start receiving, figure out the size beforehand, either in a request header or some other side-channel information. Only attempt to Receive that much data.
- Have the sending software close the socket after sending the data. If this is from an http request, for instance, you can specify `Connection: close` in the request header. When they close the connection, Receive will pop out (via exception - connection closed by peer) and you'll know you're done.
- This is hackish, but .. set a receive timeout that's larger than the time it takes to receive even the slowest chunk. After you hit the end of the stream, your receive call will timeout (via exception) and you'll know you're done. I don't recommend this way.